# CSS3 Simultaneous Image Rotation, Scaling, animating and Opacity reduction

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create a Metro Style Website and want to add Buttons like in the following :

http://themeforest.net/item/metro-lab-responsive-metro-dashboard-template/full_screen_preview/5359122

When we hover over the 'New User', 'Sales' etc Tabs, the icons/Images in the tabs rotates, increases its size and looses opacity.

But I am not able to get the exact output. I get only 2 outputs at a time :
--> Opacity and Scaling
--> Opacity and Rotation

but not all of them simultaneously.

You can see where I had reached at :

http://developer.nuevothoughts.com/jiteen/attendance/docs/#

My Current CSS is :

```
.icon-rocket{
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
-o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
transition-duration: 0.8s;

-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
-moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
-o-transition-property: -o-transform;
transition-property: transform;

overflow:hidden;

}  

.icon-rocket:hover  
{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);

/******************************/

-webkit-transform: scale(2.5,2.5);
-moz-transform:scale(2.5,2.5);
opacity: 0.5;
-moz-opacity: 0.5; 
}
```

I would appreciate any kind of Help in this.

Comment: Transform functions can (and should) be combined into one: `transform:rotate(360deg) scale(2.5);`.

Comment: They not only _should_ in this case, they _must_ – otherwise the second declaration of the property of course overwrites the first one.

Comment: Passerby, Thank you sir. Your One-Line Code really helped me to achieve what I wanted.

Comment: I had modified my Code and now it can be seen :
http://developer.nuevothoughts.com/jiteen/attendance/docs/#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add following code

```
.main_tab.shortcut.span2.padding20.text-center a:hover i {
  font-size: 40px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

and remove the hover you used (icon-rocket:hover)

Comment: It was quite helpful. I did it by using following code:

    .main_tab.shortcut.span2.padding20.text-center a:hover i {
      font-size: 40px;
      opacity: 0.5;
      transform:rotate(45deg) scale(3);
      overflow : hidden;
    }